# Google Insights Page Speed API unable to connect server error

Tags: c#-4.0, pagespeed, google-pagespeed-insights-api

I am dealing with the Google Insight Page Speed API and I have come across a weird errors that state "PageSpeed was unable to connect to the server. Ensure that you are using the correct protocol (http vs https), the page loads in a browser, and is accessible on the public Internet." and "Unable to process request. Please wait a while and try again."

I tried finding with its forum but hard luck I didn't found any

[Google Insight Page Speed Forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/pagespeed-insights-discuss)

Also, I have searched for related question which are

[PageSpeed was unable to connect to the server](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pagespeed-insights-discuss/wyDUyGy4r8s)
and
[Timeout error](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pagespeed-insights-discuss/xM7dNiMOLLs)

You can check my API call.
https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v2/runPagespeed?url=http://stackoverflow.com&strategy=Mobile&key=API_KEY

I want to overcome over these errors.
Looking forward for your response.

Answer (score 0):

The Pagespeed API will throw this error when it is being overloaded. If you're making multiple calls to the API you might want to slow down the call rate to implement some type of retry functionality.